# Errors while compiling Python with SSL support

Tags: python, ssl, build

I'm trying to compile Python 2.7.3 on Centos6. Almost everything works ok, except the thing I really need ^^.

When I type make, I'm getting the error:

```
building '_ssl' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/root/Python-2.7.3/Include -I/root/Python-2.7.3 -c /root/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ssl.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/root/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ssl.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/root/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ssl.o -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/_ssl.so
*** WARNING: renaming "_ssl" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: krb5_auth_con_getrcache
```

And at the end I'm getting a message that the build failed for module _ssl (something like this).

Have you ever faced this problem? I have installed both OpenSSL (0.9.8e fips) and OpenSSL-dev.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the right paths to openssl-dev (lib and include) are in your Makefile

Comment: I think that paths are right. Probably my OpenSSL is not suitable, i dont know.